# Unable to serve static resources with spring, receive index instead

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a simple Spring web application.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    GreetingRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        repository.save(greeting);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Greeting Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css file that is referenced in the HTML:

```
p {
    color: #ff5588;
}
```

However, the css is not applied.

In fact, when I query localhost:8080/css/style.css it returns the HTML content of the index page.

Comment: Is there a security implementation (SpringSecurity or custom) on your project? If so, does your user have access to '/css/*' url or this url has public access?  The redirection might be occur if user doesn't have access to url or there is an exception while processing request.

Comment: That turned out to be it. Can you please post that as an answer? Then I can upvote it and give you rep.

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security configuration turned out to be blocking all requests to resources. In stead, it was redirecting those requests to the index page (which was configured).

The solution turned out to be simple, authorize all requests to the resources of the website (`/images/**` and `/css/**` and `/js/**`).

Once that was configured, the web-application worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a security configuration issue. Is there a security implementation (SpringSecurity or custom) on your project? If so, does your user have access to `/css/*` url or this url has public access? The redirection might be occur if user doesn't have access to url or there is an exception while processing request.